# Adjust height and width of a draggable component as per the text entered in flutter

Tags: flutter, textarea, height, width, dynamically-generated

I am building a flutter application with draggable nodes. The issue I am facing is the node is not adjusting its width as per the length of the text entered. The height also expands only for a certain length and will show overflow issue after that. Please find the code :

```
class BaseComponentBody extends StatelessWidget {
  final ComponentData componentData;
  final CustomPainter componentPainter;

  const BaseComponentBody({
    Key key,
    this.componentData,
    this.componentPainter,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final MyComponentData customData = componentData.data;

    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        //decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
             Expanded(
             child: Column(
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
               children: [
                 new Container(
                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                       border: Border.all(color: Colors.black,width:0.5),
                         //color: Colors.white,
                         color: customData.color_classandproperty,
                      ),
                     child: Text(
                         customData.classproperty,
                         style: TextStyle(fontSize: customData.textSize-7,
                      )),
                 ),

                 new Container(
                   // margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                   //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                   //height:componentData.size.height,
                   //width:componentData.size.width-35,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black,width:0.5),
                      color: customData.color,
                   ),
                   child: Text(customData.text,
                           style: TextStyle(fontSize: customData.textSize-7,)
                   ),
                  )
               ],

             ),
           )],
      ),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: replace Container with Expanded

Comment: hi Sanketh thank you for the reply. I tried this solution by replacing the outer container with expanded but still I got an overflow error.

Comment: not the outer container, the one inside Row / Column which is giving you this error

Comment: I tried it but replacing it shows error with Box decoration widget.